# Stack underflow and stack overflow error in PIC18F

Tags: pic, proteus

I'm trying to run a motor in clockwise and anticlockwise direction using pic18f65k22 in MPLAB X IDE

```
LIST P=18F65K22
#INCLUDE "P18F65K22.inc"



    CBLOCK 0x20
    COUNT1
    ENDC

    ORG 0x00
    GOTO MAIN


    MAIN:
    MOVLW 0x00
    MOVWF TRISD

    BSF PORTD,0
    CALL DELAY
    BCF PORTD,1
    CALL DELAY
    BSF PORTD,1
    CALL DELAY
    BCF PORTD,0

    DELAY:
    MOVLW D'51'
    MOVWF COUNT1
    CALL DELAY


    GOTO MAIN


    END
```

Comment: You really need to provide more details. What is the exact error you're receiving? Screenshots and/or copy-pastes would be very useful here.

Comment: Wait what? Given that code, does it take more than a second to see there's a stack depth problem in it???

Comment: @BrianDrummond even if it wasn't glaringly obvious, a moment with a debugger would highlight it...

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: Apparently, you can't help shouting in the title. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELAY:
MOVLW D'51'
MOVWF COUNT1
CALL DELAY
```

That is recursive, it calls itself. That is going to overflow your stack very quickly.